# Find Replace from excel to word template macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, macros, microsoft-excel-2016

I want to use excel to find (ColA) data and replace it with (ColB) Data in to a premade word template

I have the macro that already opens up the word template with what i want to find/replace

I am having trouble on getting the find replace to happen

I have low VBA/Excel skills

here is my code I have for the find replace loop

I have CustRow wanting to be Column A
and DataRow wanting to be Column B

I want the macro to include any thing else that gets added to ColA later on, hence the hopefully correct usage of ".Range("A9999").End(xlUp).Row"?

```
LastRow = .Range("A9999").End(xlUp).Row 'Determine Last Row in Table

           For CustRow = 1 To LastRow

                                Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=DocLoc, ReadOnly:=False) 'Open Template

                                DataRow = .Range("B9999").End(xlUp).Row

                                For DataRow = 2 To DataRow 'Move through Bcol

                                    TagName = .Cells(2, CustRow).Value 'Tag Name

                                    TagValue = .Cells(CustRow, DataRow).Value 'Tag Value

                                     With WordDoc.Content.Find

                                        .Text = TagName

                                        .Replacement.Text = TagValue

                                        .Wrap = wdFindContinue

                                        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll 'Find & Replace all instances

                                    End With

                                    Next DataRow

                       

                        

                                   If .Range("K1").Value = "Word" Then

                                       FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & .Range("A6").Value & "_" & .Range("A11").Value & ".docx"

                                       WordDoc.SaveAs FileName

                                    End If
```

Excel Doc looks like

- A               --B--
- --name--            **bob**
- --Address--   1234 Yargh St

and so on

My Word template has all things I want to replace with the same text that is in column A
My hopes is to have the macro replace in the word template --Name-- with Bob and so on.

I am think my issues are with code lines 1,2,4,5,6,7

Thanks for any help

Comment: If you put your excel info in a table it will be easier to loop through.

Comment: Look into using Mail Merge in Word, instead of vba. --- Pivot your data so that what is now in column A is instead Row 1 and the data is in the rows below your labels that are now in row 1. -- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-mail-merge-for-bulk-email-letters-labels-and-envelopes-f488ed5b-b849-4c11-9cff-932c49474705?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us